# Graphing Line Inside Rectangle

Tags: c++, codeblocks, openframeworks

I am using `Codeblock` and `Openframeworks` (C++). I am trying to create a line inside of a rectangle that I drew. `(0,0)` is my `origin`, used `ofPushMatrix` to move the coordinate system to be center. Anyways, the rectangle that I drew, which doesn't take all of the screen, the dimension of the rectangle is `800 by 800`. Therefor using the `ofRect` function it starts at `coords (-400,-400)` and ends at `(400,400)`.

So the problem that I am having is drawing a simple `y = mx + b`, line inside this rectangle. I have the slope and intercept. This is what I am playing around with right now, but not working.

```
ofPoint ofApp::getPT1coords(float slope, float intercept)
{
    pt1.x = (-400 - intercept) / slope;
    pt1.y = -400 * slope + intercept;

    if(pt1.x < -400)
        pt1.x = -400;
    if(pt1.y < -400)
        pt1.y = -400;

    return(pt1);
}
```

Comment: What is "not working"? The fact that you get (-400,-400) for out-of-bounds values?

Comment: The line is being drawn out of the rectangle. Both points can't go out of bounds (I believe).